# ¿Como insistir al usuario que ingrese solo numeros sin que me cierre el programa por un error?

Tags: python, string, funciones, bucles, int

Necesito validar 2 input() y necesito saber si los valores son números y no Strings para poder compararlos **sin usar** la función "isdigit()" y "isalpha()".
Basicamente quiero hacer un bucle en el cual insista al usuario ingresar un número, pero no se como implementarlo.

```
def max():
    n1, n2 =  input("Ingresa el 1er numero: "), input("Ingresa el 2do numero: ")
    try:        
        n1 = int(n1)
        n2 = int(n2)        
    except ValueError:
        print("solo se puede comparar numeros, no caracteres")
    else:
        print("son validos")

max()
```

Comment: Pues deberías empezar usando un bucle... no veo ninguno en tu código, así obviamente no va a hacerlo. Si tienes un error concreto podemos ayudarte pero la solución a "no sé cómo implementarlo" es empezar a intentarlo al menos.

Comment: Usa un ciclo y haz que la condición de parada sea validar algo que te indique que ya se cumplió el requisito que deseas

Comment: Crea una función con un `while` infinito. Dentro del `while` un `try/except` y en él conviertes la entrada del usuario de cadena a entero. Si no da error, lo retornas; si da error, seguirá dentro del ciclo.

Comment: Deberías cambiarle el nombre a tu función para que no coincida con la función integrada [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def max():
    n1 = elije( "Ingresa el 1er número: " )
    n2 = elije( "Ingresa el 2do número: " )
    print( "son validos" )

def elije( cual ):
    while True:
        num = input( cual )
        try:        
            n1 = int( num )  
            return n1
        except ValueError:
            print( "solo se puede comparar números, no caracteres" )
            
max()
```

Sacando de la función **max** la inicialización de las variables, se hace más sencillo lograr el objetivo.
Básicamente use tu código, con el agregado de un `while`, que uso, para volver a pedirle el número al usuario, en caso de necesidad.
Si la conversión a `int` tiene éxito, la función retorna el valor ingresado, sino, el bucle se repite.

Edición, corregí el mensaje enviado a **elejir** gracias al comentario de @Mateo.

Comment: Es solo una opinión: suelo hacer que la función reciba el mensaje completo que debe mostrar. De hecho, una opción todavía más genérica es que la función reciba otras funciones como parámetros. Una que se ejecute cuando ocurra un error y así.

Comment: @Mateo, corregida la primer parte, gracias totales!!, lo otro no lo entendí.

Comment: Si ese es el único uso que le iba a dar, no hay problema por ahorrar algo de código. Pero de esta forma se puede reutilizar para otras cosas.